# geometric_shapes_msgs has not been declared

Tags: ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im following this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Specifying%20pose%20goals, and it says geometric_shapes_msgs has not been declared.
I check the package and it's not in my ros system (fuerte, 12.04). do I need to install that package separately? Thanks in advance

```
rosmake example_ompl_tutorials 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['example_ompl_tutorials']                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-215257
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['example_ompl_tutorials'] to:
['example_ompl_tutorials']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs  No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                  
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole         
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                   
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                  
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs             
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> opende [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                 
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< actionlib  No Makefile in package actionlib           
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                 
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> resource_retriever [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom          
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                          
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< opende ROS_NOBUILD in package opende                  
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> arm_navigation_msgs [ make ]                          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                               
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice         
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< arm_navigation_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package arm_navigation_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< resource_retriever ROS_NOBUILD in package resource_retriever
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                          
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> geometric_shapes [ make ]                             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_qt_binding [ make ]                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                      
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib            
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser  
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> filters [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
 No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                              
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< geometric_shapes ROS_NOBUILD in package geometric_shapes
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_qt_binding ROS_NOBUILD in package python_qt_binding
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs             
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> laser_geometry [ make ]                               
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< laser_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package laser_geometry  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> interactive_markers [ make ]                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> planning_models [ make ]                              
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                          
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> ogre_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< planning_models ROS_NOBUILD in package planning_models
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< interactive_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package interactive_markers
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> collision_space [ make ]                              
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< ogre_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre_tools          
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< collision_space ROS_NOBUILD in package collision_space
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rviz [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rviz ROS_NOBUILD in package rviz                      
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< filters ROS_NOBUILD in package filters                
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> robot_self_filter [ make ]                            
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< robot_self_filter ROS_NOBUILD in package robot_self_filter
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> planning_environment [ make ]                         
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< planning_environment ROS_NOBUILD in package planning_environment
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> example_ompl_tutorials [ make ]                       
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesample_ompl_tutorials: 2... [ 1 Active 54/55 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package example_ompl_tutorials
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build
  cd build && make -j8 -l8
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  [ 50%] [100%] Built target ompl_joint_goal
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ompl_pose_goal.dir/src/ompl_pose_goal.o
  /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/src/ompl_pose_goal.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/src/ompl_pose_goal.cpp:37:103: error: ‘geometric_shapes_msgs’ has not been declared
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ompl_pose_goal.dir/src/ompl_pose_goal.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ompl_pose_goal.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anshar/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/example_ompl_tutorials/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package example_ompl_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-215257/example_ompl_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< example_ompl_tutorials [FAIL] [ 2.96 seconds ]        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package example_ompl_tutorials. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                           
[ rosmake ] Built 55 packages with 1 failures.                                 
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                        
[ rosmake ] /home/anshar/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130514-215257
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62689/geometric_shapes_msgs-has-not-been-declared/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved, since the motion_planning_msgs has been changed to arm_navigation_msgs, geometric_shapes_msgs is not longer valid, replaced by arm_navigation_msgs itself.

---

Originally posted by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) with karma: 128 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0